# Remove spacing between images UIL

Tags: android, android-imageview, universal-image-loader

I'm trying to inflate several imageviews in a horizontal scroll view using Universal image loader and following code

```
for (int i = 0; i < received_params.length; i++) { //received_params ARRAY CONTAING URLs
            final ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = null;
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            image.setLayoutParams(params);

            imageLoader.displayImage(received_params[i], image, options);   
            scrnshts_ll.addView(image); //scrnshts_ll is the object of Linear Layout image_view_ll
        }
```

and my horizontal scroll view is

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
android:id="@+id/image_view_hll"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="250dp"
android:background="@color/overlay_bg"
android:padding="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/image_view_ll"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

now my problem can clearly be seen in attached image, in which there is a spacing b/w every image. `I want to remove gaps b/w images`. How to do it.[image]

Comment: i think please check your image that will be get from server.i think space is inculded in this images

Comment: but i can't open your link right now.so please put that images in postimg.org

Comment: @dipali http://s28.postimg.org/67o92wa19/cat_vs_dog_5.png

Comment: @ nitin which gap remove? small circle images?

Comment: @dipali there is a consecutive gap between images, how to remove it.

Comment: Please try fitInside option

Comment: @dipali there is no `fitinside` available in `ENUM SCALETYPE`

Comment: img.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44837/discussion-between-nitin-misra-and-dipali)

Comment: @NitinMisra: you have used android:layout_height="250dp" here its hardcore pixels plz change it to android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: @varun i tried that too no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imageLoader.loadImage(received_params[i], new ImageLoadingListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    int width = loadedImage.getWidth();
                    ImageView image = new ImageView(AppDetailsActivity.this);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( (int)(width), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    }

                    params.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
                    image.setLayoutParams(params);
                    image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    image.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
                    scrnshts_ll.addView(image);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

You can try to use width of `Image` instead of `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`

Answer (score 0):

Did you trying setting scaletype on the images? Try to use scaletype as fitXY. Also make sure that you are setting the image as a source to the imageview and not as a background image.

Comment: i tried it already, `FITXY` and also `FITCENTER` but images spans and looks so weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using RelativeLayout instead LinearLayout.